# conditional axios call for toggling state with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a pretty simple method/function that I'm calling in Vue upon button click, which changes state (also toggles text on the button).

```
pauseTask: function() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      this.pauseButton.text = this.isOpen ? 'Pause' : 'Resume';
},
```

It works perfectly, but I need to make an axios call each time based on the state so if `this.isOpen` then I want to call:

```
axios.post('/item/status/pause',data)
        .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        console.log(response.data);
        if (response.data.success == false) {
            this.errors = [];
            const errorLog = Object.entries(response.data.errors);
            for (var i = errorLog.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                console.log(errorLog[i][1][0]);
                this.errors.push(errorLog[i][1][0]);
            }
        }
    });
```

and if `!this.isOpen` then:

```
axios.post('/item/status/resume',data)
        .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        console.log(response.data);
        if (response.data.success == false) {
            this.errors = [];
            const errorLog = Object.entries(response.data.errors);
            for (var i = errorLog.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                console.log(errorLog[i][1][0]);
                this.errors.push(errorLog[i][1][0]);
            }
        }
    });
```

How exactly can I achieve this with the current structure?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @KeithNicholas I have the axios calls and the working function, I'm just wondering how to properly toggle the axios call based on the state, structurally

Comment: `axios.post(\`/item/status/${this.isOpen ? 'pause' : 'resume'}\`, data)`

Comment: @Phil not sure why I didn't realize that could be done. That worked perfectly! thank you, if you answer this I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id make a seperate js ( or ts ) file for talking to you API and put those calls into it, then import it as a 'itemService' or something

So from your "pauseTask" you could then do

```
if(this.isOpen) { itemService.pause(item) } else {itemService.resume(item)}
```

or you can trigger it on a watch for isOpen

```
 watch: {
    isOpen: function (val) {
       if(val) { itemService.pause(item) } else {itemService.resume(item)}
    }
```

the advantage of the watch is that anything that manipulates isOpen will trigger the calls.